# How partial derivatives act on function argument.

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

This question arises from a physics question, where in the working the author wrote $$\int^b_a \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[K(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)\right]\, du=-\int^b_a \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left[K(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)\right]\, du,$$
where $t$, $x$ and $u$ are variables and $c$ is a constant. $K(t')$ is just a function. The integral on the right-hand side can then be evaluated using the FTC.

Why is this change in derivative variable allowed? At first I thought it was the chain rule, but then the right-hand side is missing a factor of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. From what I can see, there is no explicit relation between $u$ and $t$.  Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Apply the derivatives: $\partial_t K(t - x/c - u) = K'(t - x/c - u) = -\partial_u K(t-x/c-u)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog When you write $K'$, that's a total derivative wrt. $t$? Then how does that lead you to the second equality?

Comment: @Landuros  It is the derivative of $K$ with respect to its argument. $$K'(t-\tfrac xc-u)=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d K(z)}{\mathrm d z}\right]_{z=t-\tfrac xc-u}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[K(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)\right]=K'(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left[K(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)\right]=K'(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)(-1)=-K'(t-\frac{x}{c}-u)$$

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't really understand the second line. How did you go from a partial derivative wrt $u$ to a total derivative? Chain rule?

Comment: @Landuros Saying “total derivative” in this context is correct but a bit misleading. Note that $K$ is *a function of one variable*.

Comment: But, yes, this is the chain rule at work: $$\small\dfrac{\partial K(t-\tfrac xc-u)}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\partial (t-\tfrac xc-u)}{\partial u}\cdot\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d K(z)}{\mathrm d z}\right]_{z:=(t-\tfrac xc-u)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Perfect, that's exactly what I needed to see.